# Does Project Structure replace build.gradle entirely?

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I am in the process of tidying up my app's build environment and, when opening `build.gradle`, I noticed this message on a brown strip:

```
You can use the Project Structure dialog to view and edit your project configuration
```

Editing settings can indeed be very convenient (and less typo-prone), but I cannot find certain settings, such as `compileOptions.encoding`, in the "Project Structure dialog":

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'de.mannodermaus.android-junit5'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    buildToolsVersion "33.0.1"
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251'
    ...
    ...
```

Does this mean that I cannot rely on the "Project Structure dialog" to provide **all** settings?